# Where is the business data?

Tags: data, business

I have recently installed Sharepoint 2010 standard edition.

I need to embed an excel spread sheet in a web part but cannot find the business data.

What should I do? Here is a screenshot [image]

Answer (score 1):

Business Data is available in SharePoint 2010 Enterprise version.

It is not available in SharePoint 2010 Standard version.

Link Refernce : http://sharepointpolice.com/blog/2010/05/03/sharepoint-2010-feature-comparison-sharepoint-foundation-2010-vs-sharepoint-2010-standardenterprise/

I suggest you to convert the SharePoint license type to Enterprise if you want to use the Business Data webparts.